# existe alguna forma de hacer este slider en Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, slider

estoy usando Angular y Bootstrap y me pidieron realizar este slider:
[image]

corrijanme si me equivoco, pero reviso la documentacion de Bootstrap y lo unico parecido es el Carousel pero creo que no me funciona, esto es un slider de pequeñas imagenes. Alguna idea de como podria hacer y que sea Responsive? debo hacerlo desde cero? Bootstrap no tiene una componente para eso? Gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: El carousel de Boostrap si puede hacer lo que muestras en la imagen, ¿porqué dices que no te funciona? ¿Qué fue lo que intentaste?

Comment: bueno...  veo que el carousel es solo para una imagen, intente ver como hacer para que pudiera contener esas imagenes pequeñas dentro pero no encontre la forma.

Comment: Mira [este ejemplo](https://www.codeply.com/go/zjZsn1ly29), un carrusel responsivo con múltiples items. Adáptalo a lo que necesites y nos avisas cómo te va

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a revisar.

Comment: Veo que no todo se muestra en la documentación. Por ejemplo también tenía la duda sobre como hacer que el menu en la barra de navegación (cuándo esté en tamaño móvil) se despliegue de forma horizontal y no vertical que es como explican en la documentación. Estaba haciéndolo con css y js aparte